# Contexts and XSS attacks

Tags: javascript, java, html, xss

As I read more about XSS attacks, I came to know that what encoding rules that you've to follow depends upon the context surrounding the string. For example, any string that goes inside the **script** tags has to be JavaScript escaped. Any that goes inside the **body** or **div** tags has to be HTML escaped.

I am writing a utility class in Java for escaping (not using tags to escape directly inside JSP). Does it mean that I'll have to supply a context attribute to my escaping method so apply the appropriate escaping rule?

Here's an example:

```
<pc:fieldRow formId="preview-model-form" fieldPojoId="${fieldSchema.key}" fieldAttribute="${fieldSchema.value}" data="${orderPreviewModel[fieldSchema.key]}"/>
```

The above statement in a JSP displays fields of the **OrderPreviewModel** class. What's the context here, and what rules should be followed?

Why not apply all three rules to each string? Why bother about context at all?

Comment: If it's a form then it's HTML.

Comment: @markspace Any harm in JS escaping it as well?

Comment: If it's not JS, then the HTML will probably show your escape sequences, and not interpret them.